# forbiddenError/403 Ajax Express Csurf - how to use Csurf correctly?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express, csrf

Hey Guys so I've been at this for a week and I can't quite figure it out.

I'm building a phaser game and I set up a scoreboard using node, it's my first time using node and I can't quite figure out how to use csurf as the documentation is so confusing.

```
 ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token
    at verifytoken (/Users/jorybraun/web/highscore/node_modules/csurf/index.js:269:11)
    at csrf (/Users/jorybraun/web/highscore/node_modules/csurf/index.js:97:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/jorybraun/web/highscore/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/jorybraun/web/highscore/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
    at /Users/jorybraun/web/highscore/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/jorybraun/web/highscore/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/Users/jorybraun/web/highscore/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at /Users/jorybraun/web/highscore/app.js:43:5
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/jorybraun/web/highscore/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/jorybraun/web/highscore/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
```

I'm getting a 403 error every time i try to send an jquery post request to my route score route from the index route. I really like to limit the access to the routes so that you can't actually visit them unless you're making an internal ajax request.

So here is my app.js file

```
// app.js
var mongodb      = require('mongodb');
var monk         = require('monk');
var credentials  = require('./credentials');
var db           = monk(credentials.uri);
var express      = require('express');
var path         = require('path');
var favicon      = require('serve-favicon');
var logger       = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser   = require('body-parser');
var csrf        = require('csurf');
var loadCsrf    = csrf({ cookie: true })
var parseForm   = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })


var scores       = require("./routes/scores");
var routes       = require('./routes/index'); 

var app          = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.use(loadCsrf);

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/scores', scores);
```

index route index.js

```
    var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

    /* GET home page. */
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
      res.render('index', { csrfToken: req.csrfToken() })
    });
```

score route scores.js

```
// scores.js 

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


// GET scores, sorted by time
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log('GET scores');
  // Get the database object we attached to the request
  var db = req.db;
  // Get the collection
  var collection = db.get('scores');
  // Find all entries, sort by time (ascending)
  collection.find({}, { sort: { score : 1 } }, function (err, docs) {
    if (err) {
        // Handle error
        console.error('Failed to get scores', err);
        res.status(500).send('Failed to get scores');
    } else {
        // Respond with the JSON object
        res.json(docs);
    }
  });
});

// GET a number of top scores
// (the /top route without a number won't work unless we add it)
router.get("/top/:number", function(req, res) {
    console.log("GET top scores");
    // Read the request parameter
    var num = req.params.number;
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get("scores");
    // Get all scores, but limit the number of results
    collection.find({}, { limit: num, sort: { score : 1 } }, function(err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Failed to get scores", err);
            res.status(500).send("Failed to get scores");
        } else {
            res.json(docs);
        }
    });
});

// POST a score
router.post("/", function(req, res) {
    module.exports = router
    console.log("POST score");
    var name = req.body.name;
    var score = Number(req.body.score);
    var email = req.body.email;
    if (!(name && score)) {
        console.error("Data formatting error");
        res.status(400).send("Data formatting error");
        return;
    }
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get("scores");    
    collection.insert({
        "name": name,
        "score": score,
        "email": email

    }, function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("DB write failed", err);
            res.status(500).send("DB write failed");
        } else {
            // Return the added score
            res.json(doc);
        }
    }); 
});


module.exports = router;
```

Ajax request in the Phaser canvas,
        function submit() {

```
    var name = prompt("Please enter your name");
    var email = prompt("Please enter your email adress, this will not be featured on the scoreboard");
    var csrf_token = "#{csrfToken}";

    $("body").bind("ajaxSend", function(elm, xhr, s){
      if (s.type == "POST") {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', csrf_token);
      }
    });


    $.post({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/scores/',
        data: {

            name: name,
            email: email,
            score: score

        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('Score posted', data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, msg) {
            console.error('AJAX error', xhr.status, msg);
        }
    });

}
```

This resuts in an error like this:

```
n.ajaxTransport.l.cors.a.crossDomain.send   @   jquery.min.js:4
n.extend.ajax   @   jquery.min.js:4
n.each.n.(anonymous function)   @   jquery.min.js:4
submit  @   game.js:263
c.SignalBinding.execute @   phaser.min.js:8
c.Signal.dispatch   @   phaser.min.js:8
c.Button.onInputUpHandler   @   phaser.min.js:12
c.SignalBinding.execute @   phaser.min.js:8
c.Signal.dispatch
```

I've tried alot of different options but if some one can help me find a simple solution that would be amazing!

Thank you

Comment: I have been posting my answer which similar to this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39264129/csurf-ajax-call-invalid-csrf-token/47962678#47962678

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured out why this isn't working - I've gone through tons of stackoverflows and tutorials and everyone said to set it in the header. I haven't tested this but i think you need to use a different csrf token for the head to work. This token is set in the body:

```
res.render('index', { csrfToken: req.csrfToken() })
```

And it's looking for a key pair value with _csrf as the key in the body. This is currently working:

```
    var csrf_Token = getCsrfToken();  
    function getCsrfToken() { 
      var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta'); 

        for (i=0; i<metas.length; i++) { 
          if (metas[i].getAttribute("name") == "_csrf") { 
             return metas[i].getAttribute("content"); 
          } 
        } 

        return "";
      } 


    $.post({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/scores/',
        data: {

            _csrf: csrf_Token,
            name: name,
            email: email,
            score: score

        },
        success: function() {
            console.log('Score posted');
        },
        error: function(xhr, msg) {
            console.error('AJAX error', xhr.status, msg);
        }
    });
```

If anyone can help me find another way to make this work I would love it as passing the token to the client through a meta tag doesn't really seem like the best way to do this.