# csurf AJAX call - invalid CSRF token

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express, csrf

I'm using the express middleware csurf for CSRF protection. If I'm using it with forms, where I put the token into a hidden field, the action behind the routes works. Now I want to make a simple AJAX call but there csurf says its invalid.

**AJAX call:**

```
$('.remove').on('click', function () {
    var csrf = $(this).attr('data-csrf');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: '/user/' + $(this).attr('data-id'),
        data: {
            _csrf: csrf
        },
        success: function (data) {
            //.....
        }
    });
});
```

And the part in the view:

```
<td class="uk-table-middle">
  <button data-id="{{ _id }}"  data-csrf="{{ csrfToken }}" class="uk-button-link uk-text-large remove">
      <i class="uk-icon-remove"></i>
  </button> 
</td>
```

And the init from the middleware:

```
import * as csurf from 'csurf';
// init bodyparse and and and...
app.use(csurf());
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know in express but usually the CSRF token is inside a cookie, so you will need these two functions:

```
 function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
```

And then:

```
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
$.ajax({
    url : formURL,
    type: "POST",
    data : postData,
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings){
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type)) xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
    },
    success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        //if fails
    }
});
```

Or if you don't want to use jQuery, you can use XMLHttpRequest to make the AJAX request:

```
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('POST', url);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
xhr.onload = function(){
     if(xhr.status === 200){
         var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
         console.log(response)
     }
 };
 xhr.send(encodeURI('category=' + cat));
```

Comment: this didn't help me. The reason why its not working was, that I send to the template an array and the token. And in the template I iterate throught the array and in this scope the token is not found.... didn't know that ._.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason why this method doesn't work is that you're not passing cookies with your ajax request. I was struggling when I figuring it out when I look into the code.

Csurf needs you to pass the secret key which stored on cookies (`_csrf`). Cookies have a limitation through the permission based on the domain (except your server allowing CORS)

On my case, I use `fetch` to passing the cookies with same domain request (i don't have to allow CORS)

```
const { _csrf, someData } = jsonData; // _csrf here you got from the form
const response = await fetch("/api/some/endpoint", {
  method: "POST",
  credentials: "same-origin", // here is the option to include cookies on this request
  headers: {
    "x-csrf-token": _csrf,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ someData })
});
```

Please note the code above I'm using es6 format. You may change `same-origin` with `include` if you requesting to different domain a.k.a CORS [see the doc here](https://github.com/github/fetch#sending-cookies)

If you using `jQuery` as the library, this code could be useful to you. This code was untested and you should find out by yourself based on what library you use.

```
 $.ajax({
   url: 'http://your.domain.com/api/some/endpoint',
   xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }, // this include cookies
   headers: {'x-csrf-token': 'YourCSRFKey'}
 })
```

Please be free to use your own names on the **headers**, **post data** or **querystring** when passing the `_csrf` value. On my example above I'm using header with name `x-csrf-token`, but you can use other method based on screenshot code below.

[image: Sample code from csurf when geting _csrf value]